# Xcode 12 Beta 2 - unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-ios14.0-simulator'

Tags: xcode, xcode12

I have just installed Xcode 12 Beta 2. Everytime I build or run it creates the following error:

> unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-ios14.0-simulator'

Any idea why that is and what I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

**VALID_ARCHS** was deprecated in Xcode 12, therefore, just delete the reference from your Project and Targets Build Settings by navigating to:

1. YourProject Settings > Build Settings > VALID_ARCHS
2. YourProject Settings > TARGETS > YourProject > Build Settings > VALID_ARCHS
3. YourProject Settings > TARGETS > UITests > Build Settings > VALID_ARCHS
4. YourProject Settings > TARGETS > UnitTests > Build Settings > VALID_ARCHS

[Image of what VALID_ARCHS should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NUgG.png)

*Highlight row and press "**delete**" key*