# Unable to load standard library for target arm64 error in XCode on Macbook Air M1

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

On new Mac with M1 chip get the error after the build of React Native app in XCode 12.4:

```
unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-ios8.0'
```

> failed to build module 'SciChart' from its module interface; the compiler that produced it, 'Apple Swift version 5.1.3 (swiftlang-1100.0.282.1 clang-1100.0.33.15)', may have used features that aren't supported by this compiler, 'Apple Swift version 5.3.2 (swiftlang-1200.0.45 clang-1200.0.32.28)'

What I already tried:

1. Reinstall XCode;
2. Changed Swift Language Version;
3. Deleted VALID_ARCHS reference according [Xcode 12 Beta 2 - unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-ios14.0-simulator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029093/xcode-12-beta-2-unable-to-load-standard-library-for-target-arm64-apple-ios14)

On Macbook with intel chip there are no errors with the same app. And both of my Macbook have the same swift version:

```
Apple Swift version 5.3.2 (swiftlang-1200.0.45 clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
```

Can you help me please!

Answer (score 2):

Guys if you have old React Native projects just build it on Xcode with rosetta and you will save your nerves and time. I was looking the decision all week, but in the total it was so easy, just run Xcode with rosetta on M1: please try to open Xcode through Rosetta - Right click on Xcode in applications folder -> Get Info -> set Open with Rosetta to true